# NMAP Python TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, nmap

I am doing a port scanning function with nmap. However, I got this type error of string indices must be integers. Can help guiding where I went wrong?

```
        self.txtarea.Clear()    
        targetServerinput = self.targethost_input.GetValue()
        if len(targetServerinput) == 0:
            empty_error = wx.MessageDialog(None,"There is no input.\nPlease Try Again.","",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
            empty_error.ShowModal()
        else:
            try:        
                targetServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(targetServerinput)    
                nm = nmap.PortScanner()
                nm.scan(targetServerIP,'1-1024')
                nm[targetServerIP]['tcp'].keys()
                for host in nm.all_hosts():
                    print('----------------------------------------------------')
                    print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].hostname()))
                        print('State : %s' % nm[host].state())
                        for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
                         print('----------')
                             lport = nm[host][proto].keys()
                             lport.sort()
                             for port in lport:
                                print('port : %s\tstate : %s' %(port,nm[host][proto][port]['state']))

                #targetServerResult = str(targetServerIP)
            except socket.gaierror:
                name_error = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Name or service not known\nPlease Try Again.","",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
                name_error.ShowModal()
```

I got this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wxloginv1.py", line 168, in scan_btnClick
    print('port : %s\tstate : %s' %(port,nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: I think he is running Python 3 looking at the print function.

Answer (score 0):

On line 168 -

```
print('port : %s\tstate : %s' %(port,nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
```

EDIT - Here is what is really happening.

The example detailed on the Python nmap usage website is actually the reason you are getting this error. The key `'state'` is not always found in `nm[host][proto][port]`. You'll want to change that for loop to only go through for specific protocols, such as TCP or UDP.

Comment: print(nm[host][proto][port]['state'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

so how can i fix it?

Comment: So that means that nm[host][proto][port] is a string. Print that out for me will you and post the results?

Comment: {'product': u'Sendmail', 'name': u'smtp', 'extrainfo': '', 'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open', 'version': u'8.14.7/8.14.7', 'conf': u'10'}
{'product': '', 'name': u'rpcbind', 'extrainfo': u'RPC #100000', 'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open', 'version': u'2-4', 'conf': u'10'}
{'product': u'CUPS', 'name': u'ipp', 'extrainfo': '', 'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open', 'version': u'1.6', 'conf': u'10'}

Comment: That's strange. Is this the example code from the Python nmap website? I am going to try running it myself and see if I get a similar error...

Comment: ya i usibng the nmap example.so i should replace ['state'] with something else? like [TCP] ?

Comment: You'll have to figure out what you can replace it with, I would recommend removing it and figuring about based on the output what you want to do. The reality is, you shouldn't be using `['state']` there because you don't always know if you will be accessing a dictionary. The Python nmap example shouldn't have it there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that setting the proto to a static ['tcp'] helped. (My question: [Python Nmap Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671509/python-nmap-parser)).

```
    import nmap                         # import nmap.py module

    nm = nmap.PortScanner()

    host = '127.0.0.1'

    nm.scan(host, '1-1024')
    nm.command_line()
    nm.scaninfo()

    for host in nm.all_hosts():
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].hostname()))
        print('State : %s' % nm[host].state())
        print('----------------------------------------------------')

    for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
            print('----------')
            print('Protocol : %s' % proto)

    lport = nm[host]['tcp'].keys()   #<------ This 'proto' was changed from the [proto] to the ['tcp'].
    lport.sort()
    for port in lport:
                    print('----------------------------------------------------')
                    print('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
                    print('----------------------------------------------------')
```