# Python Nmap Parser

Tags: python, nmap

I'm playing with the nmap parser for python located at (http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/). It provides a sample code snippet that I used in a .py script in order to do routine checks, automating some tasks. However I get a error on "Line 25". Can someone please help me..?

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-2223')
nm.command_line()
nm.scaninfo()

for host in nm.all_hosts():
    print('----------------------------------------------------')
    print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].
    print('State : %s' % nm[host].state())
    for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
         print('----------')
         print('Protocol : %s' % proto)
         lport = nm[host][proto].keys()
         lport.sort()
         for port in lport:
             print ('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
             print('----------------------------------------------------')
```

ERROR Below:

```
    root@server:~/python/python# python MyApp.py 
    ----------------------------------------------------
    Host : 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
    State : up
    ----------
    Protocol : addresses
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MyApp.py", line 25, in <module>
        print ('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
    root@damnation:~/python/python#
```

Line 25, is the second last print line from the bottom. 'port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]'.

any advice would be great. thank you .

Comment: Port is an integer, so either use str(port) to convert it to a string in line 25 or change your print statement's format to '%d' for integer.

Comment: Thnx, I tried both your suggestions, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: if I remove 'state' completely I get this output ---> port : 80 state : {'product': u'lighttpd', 'state': u'open', 'version': u'1.4.28', 'name': u'http', 'conf': u'10', 'extrainfo': '', 'reason': u'syn-ack', 'cpe': ''}

Comment: How about `print('port : '+port+'\tstate : '+ nm[host][proto][port]['state'])`? What's that print out? I'm guessing that your state object is not a string.

Comment: hey hd1, it returns the following "File "MyApp.py", line 22, in <module>
    print('port : '+port+'\tstate : '+ nm[host][proto][port]['state'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers".  The same error.

Comment: This is what the script looks like now. http://pastebin.com/KRWwQUgr

Comment: And... what's the output?

Comment: posted it already.        "File "MyApp.py", line 22, in <module> print('port : '+port+'\tstate : '+ nm[host][proto][port]['state']) TypeError: string indices must be integers". The same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47222/discussion-between-hd1-and-dusty-boshoff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that specifying the proto in the lport param enabled the for bundled loop to correctly see the strings within the dict. Below is the correct script that allows for the python-nmap parser to work correctly. Obviously the for bundle only caters for TCP, however another params with for bundle would suffice for the UDP requirement.

```
    import nmap                         # import nmap.py module

    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    nm.scan(host, '1-1024')
    nm.command_line()
    nm.scaninfo()

    for host in nm.all_hosts():
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].hostname()))
        print('State : %s' % nm[host].state())
        print('----------------------------------------------------')

    for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
            print('----------')
            print('Protocol : %s' % proto)

    lport = nm[host]['tcp'].keys()   #<------ This 'proto' was changed from the [proto] to the ['tcp'].
    lport.sort()
    for port in lport:
                    print('----------------------------------------------------')
                    print('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
                    print('----------------------------------------------------')
```

I'm not a python expert(yet) and had some help from a friend (Tx AdriaanDL :)). However it does sort out the problem I have been having with this sample that the nmap.py developers have on their website.